# One save function for all metaboxes

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a function to set up metaboxes. This creates them when a class is instantiated with a custom name.

Now the `init()` execute two `add_action` functions. One to add the metabox and one to save the metabox.

Creating the metabox works fine. However saving doesn't
It only saves the last created metabox to the database.

```
class metaBox {
    final public function init() {
        add_action( 'add_meta_boxes', [ $this, 'add' ] );
        add_action( 'save_post', [ $this, 'save' ] );
    }

    public $CMB_Name;// for custom name

    public function setName( $CMB_Name ) {
        $this->CMB_Name = $CMB_Name;
    }

    public function add() { // to add the metabox
        add_meta_box(
            $this->CMB_Name,
            __( $this->CMB_Name, 'plugin' ),
            [ $this, 'display' ],
            'page',
            'normal',
            'high'
        );
    }

    public function save( $post_id ) {// to save the metabox
        $is_autosave    = wp_is_post_autosave( $post_id );
        $is_revision    = wp_is_post_revision( $post_id );
        $is_valid_nonce = ( isset( $_POST['nonce_check_value'] ) && wp_verify_nonce( $_POST['nonce_check_value'], basename( __FILE__ ) ) ) ? 'true' : 'false';

        // Exits script depending on save status
        if ( $is_autosave || $is_revision || ! $is_valid_nonce ) {
            return;
        }
        if ( isset( $_POST[ $this->CMB_Name . '-text' ] ) ) {
            update_post_meta( $post_id, $this->CMB_Name . '-text', sanitize_text_field( $_POST[ $this->CMB_Name . '-text' ] ) );
        }
    }
}
```

What I don't understand is that it doesn't save both values while there are unique nonces and names to the metaboxes .

The objects are created like this:

```
function mbe_start() {
    $plugin = new testForm();
    $plugin->setName( "OOP Plugin name" );
    $plugin->init();

    $plugin1 = new anotherForm();
    $plugin1->setName( "whaat" );
    $plugin1->init();
}
mbe_start();
```

Why doesn't the save function work? I mean it's principle is exactly like the one that adds the metabox.

If I disable the `isset()` function it throws me a notice about an `Undefined index` for the **first** metabox. Not really sure why and/or how to fill it.

Answer (score 0):

OMG.....

Got it working. The reason is that the name given contains spaces and capital letters. This caused the problem.

Fixed it by replacing the name with
`strtolower(preg_replace('/-+/', '-', preg_replace('/[^\wáéíóú]/', '-', $this->CMB_Name)));`